# php - create csv export file, based on product values

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv, script

I currently have the following script, that change the producttitle of a product with a specific ID.

Now I want to re-write the script, so that it does not update the attributes but generates a .csv file of the entire catalog with two columns.

1. Product_SKU
2. $productnamingseo value

How can I achieve this?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(409728);
Mage::register('current_product', $product);
$seotitle = Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentSeo();
$productnamestring = Mage::getSingleton('seo/object_product')->getTitle();

        $findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', '/\s*-\s*$/');
        $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3', '');
        $productnamingseo = preg_replace($findseo, $replaceseo, $productnamestring);

$product->setName($productnamingseo);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'name');
```

EDIT already tried this, that works for only 1 product. All other products got that $productnamingseo value of product 1, instead of their own unique value.

This create a .csv file with the following output. Only the first line is correct. All other lines got the wrong $productnamingseo of the first product.

```
"ACER_EY.JE001.002","Acer C120 LED - EY.JE001.002"
"ALLIEDTELESIS_AT-2701FXA/SC-001","Acer C120 LED - EY.JE001.002"
"APC_0M-0213-005","Acer C120 LED - EY.JE001.002"
```

Script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');

require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$file_path = "var/import/productname.csv";
$mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(1)->setCurPage(1);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $prod = Mage::register('current_product', $product);
    $seotitle = Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentSeo();
    $productnamestring = Mage::getSingleton('seo/object_product')->getTitle();

    $findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', '/\s*-\s*$/');
    $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3', '');
    $productnamingseo = preg_replace($findseo, $replaceseo, $productnamestring);

    echo $productnamingseo;

    $data = array();
    $data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
    $data['name'] = $productnamingseo;
    $products_row[] = $data;

    Mage::unregister('current_product')
}

$mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $products_row);
echo 'Done!';
```

SEO helper Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Object_Product:

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if (!$this->_product) {
        $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
    }
    if (!$this->_product) {
        return;
    }


    $this->_parseObjects['product'] = $this->_product;

    $this->setAdditionalVariable('product', 'url', $this->_product->getProductUrl());
    $this->setAdditionalVariable('product', 'final_price', $this->_product->getFinalPrice());
    $this->setAdditionalVariable('product', 'final_price_minimal', Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentProductFinalPrice($this->_product));
    $this->setAdditionalVariable('product', 'final_price_range', Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentProductFinalPriceRange($this->_product));
    $this->setAdditionalVariable('product', 'stock_qty', Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentProductStockQty($this->_product));


    $categoryId = $this->_product->getSeoCategory();
    $this->_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

    if ($this->_category && !$categoryId) {
        $this->_parseObjects['category'] = $this->_category;
    } elseif ($this->_product) {
        if (!$categoryId) {
            $categoryIds = $this->_product->getCategoryIds();
            if (count($categoryIds) > 0) {
                //we need this for multi websites configuration
                $categoryRootId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like' => "%/{$categoryRootId}/%"));

                //don't delete (for some stores need main_table)
                $stringSelect = $category->getSelect()->__toString();
                $entityIdFilter = (strpos($stringSelect, 'main_table') !== false)
                    ? 'main_table.entity_id' : 'entity_id';

                $category = $category->addFieldToFilter($entityIdFilter, $categoryIds)
                            ->setOrder('level', 'desc')
                            ->setOrder($entityIdFilter, 'desc')
                            ->getFirstItem()
                        ;
                $categoryId = $category->getId();
            }
        }
        //load category with flat data attributes
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $this->_category = $category;
        $this->_parseObjects['category'] = $category;
        if (!Mage::registry('seo_current_category')) {// to be sure that register will not be done twice
            Mage::register('seo_current_category', $category);
        };
    }

    $this->_parseObjects['store'] = Mage::getModel('seo/object_store');

    $this->init();
}
```

getCurrentSeo() code:

```
public function getCurrentSeo()
{
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'admin') {
        return new Varien_Object();
    }

    $isCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') || Mage::registry('category');
    $isProduct  = Mage::registry('current_product') || Mage::registry('product');
    $isFilter   = false;

    if ($isCategory) {
        $filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
        $isFilter = count($filters) > 0;
    }

    if ($isProduct) {
        $seo = Mage::getSingleton('seo/object_product');
    } elseif ($isCategory && $isFilter) {
        $seo =  Mage::getSingleton('seo/object_filter');
    } elseif ($isCategory) {
        $seo =  Mage::getSingleton('seo/object_category');
    } else {
        $seo = new Varien_Object();
    }

    if ($seoTempalate = $this->checkTempalateRule($isProduct, $isCategory, $isFilter)) {
        foreach ($seoTempalate->getData() as $k=>$v) {
            if ($v) {
               $seo->setData($k, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($seoRewrite = $this->checkRewrite()) {
        foreach ($seoRewrite->getData() as $k=>$v) {
            if ($v) {
               $seo->setData($k, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $page    = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('p');
    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if ($isCategory && !$isProduct) {
        if ($this->_titlePage) {
            switch ($this->_config->getMetaTitlePageNumber($storeId)) {
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_PAGE_NUMBER_BEGIN:
                    if ($page > 1) {
                        $seo->setMetaTitle(Mage::helper('seo')->__("Page %s | %s", $page, $seo->getMetaTitle()));
                        $this->_titlePage = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_PAGE_NUMBER_END:
                    if ($page > 1) {
                        $seo->setMetaTitle(Mage::helper('seo')->__("%s | Page %s", $seo->getMetaTitle(), $page));
                        $this->_titlePage = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_PAGE_NUMBER_BEGIN_FIRST_PAGE:
                    $seo->setMetaTitle(Mage::helper('seo')->__("Page %s | %s", $page, $seo->getMetaTitle()));
                    $this->_titlePage = false;
                    break;
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_PAGE_NUMBER_END_FIRST_PAGE:
                    $seo->setMetaTitle(Mage::helper('seo')->__("%s | Page %s", $seo->getMetaTitle(), $page));
                    $this->_titlePage = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_descriptionPage) {
            switch ($this->_config->getMetaDescriptionPageNumber($storeId)) {
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_PAGE_NUMBER_BEGIN:
                    if ($page > 1) {
                        $seo->setMetaDescription(Mage::helper('seo')->__("Page %s | %s", $page, $seo->getMetaDescription()));
                        $this->_descriptionPage = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_PAGE_NUMBER_END:
                    if ($page > 1) {
                        $seo->setMetaDescription(Mage::helper('seo')->__("%s | Page %s", $seo->getMetaDescription(), $page));
                        $this->_descriptionPage = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_PAGE_NUMBER_BEGIN_FIRST_PAGE:
                    $seo->setMetaDescription(Mage::helper('seo')->__("Page %s | %s", $page, $seo->getMetaDescription()));
                    $this->_descriptionPage = false;
                    break;
                case Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_PAGE_NUMBER_END_FIRST_PAGE:
                    $seo->setMetaDescription(Mage::helper('seo')->__("%s | Page %s", $seo->getMetaDescription(), $page));
                    $this->_descriptionPage = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($page > 1) {
            $seo->setDescription(''); //set an empty description for page with number > 1 (to not have a duplicate content)
        }
    }

    if ($metaTitleMaxLength = $this->_config->getMetaTitleMaxLength($storeId)) {
        $metaTitleMaxLength = (int)$metaTitleMaxLength;
        if ($metaTitleMaxLength < Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_INCORRECT_LENGTH) {
            $metaTitleMaxLength = Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH; //recommended length
        }
        $seo->setMetaTitle($this->_getTruncatedString($seo->getMetaTitle(), $metaTitleMaxLength, $page));
    }

    if ($metaDescriptionMaxLength = $this->_config->getMetaDescriptionMaxLength($storeId)) {
        $metaDescriptionMaxLength = (int)$metaDescriptionMaxLength;
        if ($metaDescriptionMaxLength < Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_INCORRECT_LENGTH) {
            $metaDescriptionMaxLength = Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH; //recommended length
        }
        $seo->setMetaDescription($this->_getTruncatedString($seo->getMetaDescription(), $metaDescriptionMaxLength, $page));
    }

    return $seo;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a general PHP question on how to write a CSV files, which has been answered numerous times, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364528/write-a-csv-file-from-a-php-array

Comment: @simonthesorcerer Not really, because I also need a solution to change it from 1 product to all products. See my edit.

Comment: So the code from the edit only saves one product instead of all products? The first or the last one?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer No the edit is the last part, to update all products and create a csv.

Comment: Yes, what happens when you execute that? Do you get an error, a message, does anything happen?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I get a PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted. I guess due to some wrong code.

Comment: @djfordz Thanks for your reply. That's what we also tried, but we can not get it done. Can you help me out with the right code you mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

> I get a PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes
>   exhausted. I guess due to some wrong code

This is not from errors in the code, but from "waste of resources". It basically means that your script is executed without errors, but the RAM that PHP is allowed to use for this process (2G in this case) is not enough, and PHP breaks while executing.

Fast & easy solution: assign more RAM!

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');
// rest of code [...]
```

But this will only help a bit. The server might become very slow while you export, or maybe you have so many SKUs and attributes that this still won't help.

It's better to use objects that are smaller, load less data etc. For example replace this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

...with this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(['sku', 'name', 'the_name_of_your_seo_attribute']);
```

...to load only the attributes you really need.

If you have a lot of products, it may also be helpful to export them in chunks of, say, 10k products:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(['sku', 'name', 'the_name_of_your_seo_attribute'])
->setPageSize(10000)->setCurPage(1);
```

(increase `setCurPage()` for each new set)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! It now does create a csv file, but only the contains now the SKU. So my previous code to load the value of $productnamingseo does not work. `Mage::register('current_product', $product);` is a important part of the previous script. What am I missing here?

Comment: I also tried $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setPageSize(10000)->setCurPage(1); but that still only loads the SKU.

Comment: `Mage::register('current_product', $product);` does not load the product, it only registers it globally. You have to adjust the `addAttributeToSelect()` part. Looking into the functionality of the SEO-helper should help - you will see which attributes are required there.

Comment: It loads many attributes and is different for each product. So we need to set it to `$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setPageSize(10000)->setCurPage(1);` So that it load all attributes. But then still the csv only contains the SKU.

Comment: This code does not load all attributes, it only loads the attributes that are configured as "visible in the product listing" in the Magento backend. You had `addAttributeToSelect('*')`, this loads all attributes. And it's too much for your server.

Comment: See my edit, that works! But when I change setPageSize(1) to setPageSize(2). I get the following error: Uncaught Mage_Core_Exception: Mage registry key "current_product" already exists

Comment: Can you help me out with this last part?

Comment: Not sure about the correct naming, but you should call `Mage::unregister('current_product')` at the end of your `foreach()` loop.

Comment: Thanks! It does remove the error, but now it loads the same $productnamingseo for all the SKU's. So in the csv file the SKU's are different, but the $productnamingseo is the name of the first product.

Comment: Hm, ok. You seem to be using a 3rd party module for this and I have no idea how the SEO helper works, so you might have to dig into this.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the question with the module code. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Any ideas to a solution?

Comment: No, because the helper calls a lot of methods/models from the module, and I don't have the code. I also don't have your configuration. AND questions on 3rd party modules are considered off-topic here. So, it's possible to achieve your desired result, but you will have to look at it by yourself I guess.

Comment: Thanks so far! Do you need more that the given code above to solve this? I really need a solution to this problem and I guess it should not be that hard. I mainly need to rewrite the foreach, so that it will first check a product and then close that product before register the next (new) product.

Comment: `I really need a solution to this problem and I guess it should not be that hard` I also think so, so go for it :)

Comment: That's what I already tried, before opening a question here. I can not find the problem and a solution to the problem.

Comment: why is registering a product with the script so important?

Comment: @djfordz Because in that case we can get the value from the seo-module. These seo-values are generated dynamically normally on the productpage, but now we need them in a script. But if you see another way, please let me know. I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: @Henk Z unfortunately, i don't have access to the module so it's difficult to come up with a solution without having access to the complete module to read how it generates these values.

Comment: @djfordz I can sent you the entire module, there are to many files to share the code right here. Can I sent it to you? I really need to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Henk Z sure, I can take a shot at it send to david.ford@transgressinc.com

Comment: @djfordz Many thanks! Just sent the wetransfer email with the module.

Comment: ok great, working on it now.

Comment: @Henk Z see latest answer. use getModel instead of getSingleton and should work

Answer (score 1):

Mirasvit uses singleton pattern everywhere and the registered product, because it assumes it is getting the data from the frontend when the product is selected. The singleton pattern is somewhat unnecessary and I feel a bad design decision on their part. However, due to using Singleton pattern, A script like this won't work as it doesn't destruct the product object, thus you get same seo information for every product

Hence, the need to rewrite all the functions used with Model pattern instead of Singleton Pattern.

I rebuilt all the Mirasvit SEO functions replacing the Singleton patterns with a Model pattern. Since it dynamically replaces the information, it is done all in the script and not through the Mirasvit classes.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '4G');

require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$file_path = "var/import/productname.csv";
$mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$products_row = $_parseObjects = $_additional = [];
$_product = null;
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_config = Mage::getModel('seo/config');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    global $_product;
    $_product = $product;
    $seo = getCurrentSeo();

    $productnamestring = $seo->getTitle();

    echo 'Seo Title: ' . $productnamestring . "\n";

    $findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', '/\s*-\s*$/');
    $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3', '');
    $productnamingseo = preg_replace($findseo, $replaceseo, $productnamestring);

    $data = array();
    $data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
    $data['name'] = $productnamingseo;
    $products_row[] = $data;
}

$mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $products_row);
echo 'Done!';

function getCurrentSeo()
{
    global $_product;
    global $_storeId;
    global $_config;

    if ($_product) {
        $seo = Mage::getModel('seo/object_product');
    } else {
        $seo = new Varien_Object();
    }

    if ($seoTempalate = checkTempalateRule()) {
        foreach ($seoTempalate->getData() as $k=>$v) {
            if ($v) {
                $seo->setData($k, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($seoRewrite = checkRewrite($_product)) {
        foreach ($seoRewrite->getData() as $k=>$v) {
            if ($v) {
                $seo->setData($k, $v);
            }
        }
    }

    $page = 1;

    if ($metaTitleMaxLength = $_config->getMetaTitleMaxLength($_storeId)) {
        $metaTitleMaxLength = (int)$metaTitleMaxLength;
        if ($metaTitleMaxLength < Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_INCORRECT_LENGTH) {
            $metaTitleMaxLength = Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_TITLE_MAX_LENGTH; //recommended length
        }
        $seo->setMetaTitle(_getTruncatedString($seo->getMetaTitle(), $metaTitleMaxLength, $page));
    }

    if ($metaDescriptionMaxLength = $_config->getMetaDescriptionMaxLength($_storeId)) {
        $metaDescriptionMaxLength = (int)$metaDescriptionMaxLength;
        if ($metaDescriptionMaxLength < Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_INCORRECT_LENGTH) {
            $metaDescriptionMaxLength = Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::META_DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH; //recommended length
        }
        $seo->setMetaDescription(_getTruncatedString($seo->getMetaDescription(), $metaDescriptionMaxLength, $page));
    }

    return $seo;
}

function checkTempalateRule($info = false)
{
    global $_product;

    if (isset($_product)) {
        $collectionProduct = Mage::getModel('seo/template')->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addFieldToFilter('rule_type', Mirasvit_Seo_Model_Config::PRODUCTS_RULE)
            ->addActiveFilter()
            ->addSortOrder();

        $seoTemplateRule = _getTempalateRule($collectionProduct,
            $_product->getId(),
            false,
            $info);
    }

    return $seoTemplateRule;
}

function _getTempalateRule($collection, $productId, $categoryId, $info)
{
    global $_additional;
    global $_storeId;
    global $_parseObjects;

    $sortOrderAppliedId = false;
    $stopRulesProcessingAppliedId = false;

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        if ($isElementApplied = _getElementApplied($productId, $item)) {
            $seoTemplateRule[$item->getId()] = $item;
            if ($item->getStopRulesProcessing() && !$stopRulesProcessingAppliedId) {
                $stopRulesProcessingAppliedId = $item->getId();
            }
            if ($item->getSortOrder() && !$stopRulesProcessingAppliedId) {
                $sortOrderAppliedId = $item->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    if ($info) {
        if ($stopRulesProcessingAppliedId) {
            $seoTemplateRule['applied'] = $stopRulesProcessingAppliedId; // stop rules processing
            $seoTemplateRule['stop_rules_processing'] = true;
        } elseif ($sortOrderAppliedId) {
            $seoTemplateRule['applied'] = $sortOrderAppliedId; // sort order
            $seoTemplateRule['sort_order'] = true;
        } elseif ($seoTemplateRule) {
            $seoTemplateRule['applied'] = key(array_slice($seoTemplateRule, -1, 1, true)); // maximal ID
        }

        return $seoTemplateRule;
    }

    if ($stopRulesProcessingAppliedId) {
        $seoTemplateRule = $seoTemplateRule[$stopRulesProcessingAppliedId]; // stop rules processing
    } elseif ($sortOrderAppliedId) {
        $seoTemplateRule = $seoTemplateRule[$sortOrderAppliedId]; // sort order
    } else {
        $seoTemplateRule = array_pop($seoTemplateRule); // maximal ID
    }

    if ($seoTemplateRule) {
        $_parseObjects = _addParseObjects();
        $seoTemplateRule->setTitle(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($seoTemplateRule->getTitle(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $seoTemplateRule->setDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($seoTemplateRule->getDescription(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $seoTemplateRule->setShortDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($seoTemplateRule->getShortDescription(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $seoTemplateRule->setFullDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($seoTemplateRule->getFullDescription(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $seoTemplateRule->setCategoryDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($seoTemplateRule->getCategoryDescription(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        prepareMetaData($seoTemplateRule);
    }

    return $seoTemplateRule;
}

function _getElementApplied($productId, $item) {
        $isElementApplied = Mage::getModel('seo/template')->getRule($item->getTemplateId())->isProductApplied($productId);

    return $isElementApplied;
}

function checkRewrite($info = false)
{
    global $_additional;
    global $_storeId;
    global $_parseObjects;

    $uri = getBaseUri();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('seo/rewrite')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addEnableFilter()
        ->setOrder('sort_order');
    $resultRewrite = false;
    foreach ($collection as $rewrite) {
        if (checkPattern($uri, $rewrite->getUrl())) {
            $resultRewrite = $rewrite;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($info && $resultRewrite) {
        return $resultRewrite;
    } elseif ($info) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($resultRewrite) {
        echo "hotes\n";
        $_parseObjects = _addParseObjects();
        $resultRewrite->setTitle(Mage::helper('parse')->parse($resultRewrite->getTitle(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $resultRewrite->setDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($resultRewrite->getDescription(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $resultRewrite->setMetaTitle(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($resultRewrite->getMetaTitle(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $resultRewrite->setMetaKeywords(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($resultRewrite->getMetaKeywords(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
        $resultRewrite->setMetaDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($resultRewrite->getMetaDescription(), $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
    }

    return $resultRewrite;
}

function _addParseObjects() {
    global $_parseObjects;
    global $_product;

    if ($_product) {
        $_parseObjects['product'] = $_product;
        setAdditionalVariable('product', 'final_price', $_product->getFinalPrice());
        setAdditionalVariable('product', 'url', $_product->getProductUrl());
        setAdditionalVariable('product', 'final_price_minimal', Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentProductFinalPrice($_product));
        setAdditionalVariable('product', 'final_price_range', Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentProductFinalPriceRange($_product));
        setAdditionalVariable('product', 'stock_qty', Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentProductStockQty($_product));
    }

    $_parseObjects['store'] = Mage::getModel('seo/object_store');
    $_parseObjects['pager'] = Mage::getModel('seo/object_pager');
    $_parseObjects['filter'] = Mage::getModel('seo/object_wrapper_filter');



    return $_parseObjects;
}

function getBaseUri()
{
    $baseStoreUri = parse_url(Mage::getUrl(), PHP_URL_PATH);

    if ($baseStoreUri  == '/') {
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    } else {
        $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $prepareUri = str_replace($baseStoreUri, '', $requestUri);
        if (substr($requestUri, 0, 1) == '/') {
            return $prepareUri;
        } else {
            return DS . $prepareUri;
        }
    }
}

function _getTruncatedString($str, $length, $page) {
    $usePageNumber       = false;
    $delimiterSymbols    = array(';', '',' ', ',', '.', '!', '?', "\n", "\r", "\r\n", '|');
    $delimiterEndSymbols = array(';', '',' ', ',', "\n", "\r", "\r\n", '|');

    if (strpos($str, ' | Page '.$page) !== false) {
        $str = str_replace(' | Page '.$page, '', $str);
        $length -= strlen(' | Page '.$page);
        $usePageNumber = true;
    }

    $truncatedString = Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($str, 0, $length);

    if(($finalStringPart = str_replace($truncatedString, '', $str))
        && !in_array(substr($finalStringPart, 0, 1), $delimiterSymbols)) {
        $truncatedStringArray = explode(" ", $truncatedString);
        if (count($truncatedStringArray) > 1) {
            array_pop($truncatedStringArray);
        }
        $truncatedString = implode(" ", $truncatedStringArray);
        if (in_array(substr($truncatedString, -1), $delimiterEndSymbols)) {
            $truncatedString = substr($truncatedString, 0, -1);
        }
    }

    if ($usePageNumber) {
        $truncatedString .= ' | Page '.$page;
    }

    return $truncatedString;
}

function setAdditionalVariable($objectName, $variableName, $value)
{
    global $_additional;
    global $_parseObjects;

    $_additional[$objectName][$variableName] = $value;
    if (isset($_parseObjects['product'])) {
        if ($objectName.'_'.$variableName == 'product_final_price_minimal') {
            $_parseObjects['product']->setData('final_price_minimal', $value);
        }
        if ($objectName.'_'.$variableName == 'product_final_price_range') {
            $_parseObjects['product']->setData('final_price_range', $value);
        }
        if ($objectName.'_'.$variableName == 'product_stock_qty') {
            $_parseObjects['product']->setData('stock_qty', $value);
        }
    }
}

function prepareMetaData($seoTemplateRule) {
    global $_additional;
    global $_product;
    global $_storeId;
    global $_parseObjects;
    global $_config;

    $metaTitle = $seoTemplateRule->getMetaTitle();
    $metaKeywords = $seoTemplateRule->getMetaKeywords();
    $metaDescription = $seoTemplateRule->getMetaDescription();

    if ($_config->isProductMetaTagsUsed() && $_product) {
        $metaTitle = trim($_product->getMetaTitle()) ? $_product->getMetaTitle() : $seoTemplateRule->getMetaTitle();
        $metaKeywords = trim($_product->getMetaKeyword()) ? $_product->getMetaKeyword() : $seoTemplateRule->getMetaKeywords();
        $metaDescription = trim($_product->getMetaDescription()) ? $_product->getMetaDescription() : $seoTemplateRule->getMetaDescription();

    }

    $seoTemplateRule->setMetaTitle(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($metaTitle, $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
    $seoTemplateRule->setMetaKeywords(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($metaKeywords, $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));
    $seoTemplateRule->setMetaDescription(Mage::helper('seo/parse')->parse($metaDescription, $_parseObjects, $_additional, $_storeId));

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But with your code I currently get the original title of a product, instead of the dynamic SEO title.

Comment: hmm, ok let me look further. I don't have seo setup so I didn't check that

Comment: @Henk Z did you try the latest answer / script?

Comment: Thanks! I tried the latest one just now, but fetching the error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /test-product.php:540`

Comment: @Henk Z oops I added that very last, just remove `return $this;` at line 540 and will work. I removed it in answer.

Comment: Thanks! It does seems to create SEO-titles to the SKU, but it seems that it does get the wrong seo profiles to the specific products. Like it does not check the seo profile conditions, based on product categories for example. So laptops now got seo titles with the name SKU - graphics cards. Which not happen on the product page. Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: I fixed some minor things in the script, but if it is not selecting the proper categories it is probably because I removed everything relating to categories in the functions I copied to the script and modified, you can just look at the corresponding Mirasvit functions and add back the category functionality.

Comment: Thanks again! But it's not the category part that is missing, it is the category selection part. That it gets the right SEO Template, based on the product categorie. Now Laptops got a Seo Title with - graphics cards. But that should only be displayed for products inside the category graphics cards. Can you help me out with this last part? Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: Go ahead and try the current iteration of the script. When I tested it does change the template_id so I am assuming it is processing the rules.

Comment: Tried a couple of things, but it is still using the wrong template. So it seems that it is not checking the templates or it is checking the templates wrong. Still uses templates that are not connected to those products. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test, because the templates are changing for me.

Comment: That's quite strange. Some product are working well and others are mapped to the wrong templated based on category. So got all printers a productname with - tablets included. Which should of course only be included for products in the category tablets. When checking the same product on frontend, it also got a other productname than inside the csv. So the mapping seems to be only wrong with this script.

Comment: Any ideas how to complete the code? I still face the problem that some products are matched to the wrong seo-templates.

Comment: It would be impossible for me to figure out without being able to recreate the issue. Since i cannot recreate the issue this is the best i can do.

Comment: I do understand that, but just to be sure, can this problem also be caused because of the field separator `"` that is used to create the csv? Because we do also have products with product titles that have a `"` sign included.

Comment: You can print out the data to the screen and then go through it in the screen instead of the csv. In fact, this is what an doing to see if it is working. Just add `print_r($seo->getData()); ` above or below the echo statement to see exactly what data the $seo variable has before it goes to the csv.

Comment: We tried a lot and it seems that our (your) current script does not work well when you use multiple SEO templates and set it with SEO Template rules for that specific template. Also Stop Further Rules Processing should be set to Yes, even to make the template work in the script. It now uses the most recent script with setting Stop Further Rules Processing to Yes. Can you check this and do you know a solution to the script to solve this?

Comment: I guess it is caused due to the removal of the category and filter part. Can you help be out by implement this also in your code? So that we get the entire default `function getCurrentSeo()`?